# Running regressions in python over multiple dataframes in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dataframes in a list as follows:

```
CGdfs = [CGdf_2002, CGdf_2003, CGdf_2004, CGdf_2005, CGdf_2006, CGdf_2007, CGdf_2008, CGdf_2009, CGdf_2010, CGdf_2011, CGdf_2012, CGdf_2013, CGdf_2014]
```

Columns in each dataframe are:

`CGdf_2002` has columns: `TSR_df_03_06, board_gender_diversity_percent, gics_sector_name, custom_region`

`CGdf_2003` has columns: `TSR_df_04_07, board_gender_diversity_percent, gics_sector_name, custom_region`

`CGdf_2014` has columns: `TSR_df_15_18, board_gender_diversity_percent, gics_sector_name, custom_region`
...

I have the TSR columns in a list too

```
TSR3yrdfs_string = ['TSR_df_03_06', 'TSR_df_04_07', 'TSR_df_05_08', 'TSR_df_06_09', 'TSR_df_07_10', 'TSR_df_08_11', 'TSR_df_09_12', 'TSR_df_10_13','TSR_df_11_14', 'TSR_df_12_15','TSR_df_13_16','TSR_df_14_17', 'TSR_df_15_18']
```

I want to run regressions on all these dataframes in a loop with the following formula:

```
sm.ols(formula = TSR_df_03_06 ~ board_gender_diversity_percent + gics_sector_name + custom_region, data=CGdf_2002).fit()

sm.ols(formula = TSR_df_04_07 ~ board_gender_diversity_percent + gics_sector_name + custom_region, data=CGdf_2003).fit()

sm.ols(formula = TSR_df_05_08 ~ board_gender_diversity_percent + gics_sector_name + custom_region, data=CGdf_2004).fit()
```

These are different formulae for each dataframe. I want to run all these regressions upto `CGdf_2014` in a loop.

Can someone give me a suggestion to achieve this?

I have tried the following but it says invalid syntax

```
CGdfs = [CGdf_2002, CGdf_2003, CGdf_2004, CGdf_2005, CGdf_2006, CGdf_2007, CGdf_2008, CGdf_2009, CGdf_2010, CGdf_2011, CGdf_2012, CGdf_2013, CGdf_2014, CGdf_2015, CGdf_2016, CGdf_2017, CGdf_2018]

TSR3yrdfs_string = ['TSR_df_03_06', 'TSR_df_04_07', 'TSR_df_05_08', 'TSR_df_06_09', 'TSR_df_07_10', 'TSR_df_08_11', 'TSR_df_09_12', 'TSR_df_10_13','TSR_df_11_14', 'TSR_df_12_15','TSR_df_13_16','TSR_df_14_17', 'TSR_df_15_18']  

for x, y in zip(CGdfs, TSR3yrdfs_string):
    results = sm.ols(formula = x[y] ~ x['board_gender_diversity_percent'] + x['gics_sector_name'] + x['custom_region'], data=x).fit()
    print('The summary of regression is:', results.summary())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `formula` as a string, but your `formula` has several lists, e.g. `x[y]`, `x['gics_sector_name']`, ... and one element, that is not a char/string: `~`.

But you can rewrite your `formula` like this (for better readability with a `formula_str` variable:

```
formula_str = y + '~' + 'board_gender_diversity_percent + gics_sector_name + custom_region'
results = sm.ols(formula=formula_str, data=x).fit()
```

`y` is a string inside your `TSR3yrdfs_string` list and your other colums just hard-coded as a single string.